# Cannot fsck a corrupted USB

Tags: usb, data-recovery, hardware, ram, testdisk

I put valuable data on a disfunctioning LUKS encrypted USB. The command

```
fsck.vfat /dev/mapper/myusb -v -y
```

seems no to be enough. I ran the command for more than 12 hours without the command to finish.

**Which alternative command to fsck would you use to repare my broken USB?**

---

To be more precise, with the previously given command, I get

```
fsck.fat 4.0 (2016-05-06)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
     32768 bytes per cluster
        64 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 32768 (sector 64)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
   6553600 bytes per FAT (= 12800 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 13139968 (sector 25664)
   1637935 data clusters (53671854080 bytes)
63 sectors/track, 255 heads
         0 hidden sectors
 104853504 sectors total
FATs differ but appear to be intact. Using first FAT.
Cluster 58370 out of range (122740383 > 1637936). Setting to EOF.
Cluster 58371 out of range (63140890 > 1637936). Setting to EOF.

[.. (1000x lines analogous to the previous one) ]

/D3«▒í╠z7.ⁿTπ
  Bad short file name (D3«▒í╠z7.ⁿTπ).
  Auto-renaming it.
  Renamed to FAOK0000.469
/║πö┌2./Φ≈
  Bad short file name (║πö┌2./Φ≈).
  Auto-renaming it.
  Renamed to FAOK0000.470
/ÿ╖Pφ╥╞.²
  Bad short file name (ÿ╖Pφ╥╞.²).
  Auto-renaming it.
  Renamed to FAO0000.471

[... (millions of lines like this, almost all my files)]
```

I tried the `-d` option to remove the specific folder but without success.

Comment: I had a similar issue at one time with my hard drive. After roughly three hours of attempting to repair it, I gave up. Simply put, I believe it may not be possible to recover your usb -- at least with fsck. Maybe there's another software or someone who can suggest something more helpful, but I've found that is fsck cannot fix it, very little can. If you can still access the drive somehow, even in read-only mode, I recommend backing it up, removing the corrupt file (if you can physically find it), trying fsck one last time, and if that fails, format the usb.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the USB is really disfunctional, I ran

```
sudo badblocks -c 10240 -s -w -t random -v /dev/sdb1
```